# Is a heavier car better than a lighter one?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am planning to build my own sports car when I am older and am very eco-friendly. I was wondering if a lighter car with everything else the same would be better than a heavier car. I am not expecting it to go up to 120 mph or something really fast, I just want it to have a really high mpg. I was thinking the lighter car would be better than a heavier car at stopping, and a heavier car would be better at accelerating, but not too heavy because it wouldn't be able to accelerate as well. So I was thinking a car with weight in the middle would be best.

Comment: when you want to build your own sportscar and high mpg is more important than speed to you, you will definitely want as little weight as possible

Comment: But if it was too light, wouldn't it take a long time to accelerate?

Comment: what, except maybe lower pressure of the wheels to the ground, makes you think that accelerating a small mass takes longer than accelerating a big mass when you use the same engine as you mentioned?

Comment: Do a search for the Ariel Atom and then think about why they went light...

Comment: A large reason cars are as heavy as they are is because it stands at the crossroads of safety, speed, and economy. Want speed and economy? Build a motorcycle but you loose safety. Want safety and speed? Shell out $$ for a carbon fiber super car. Want safety and economy? Design a car that maxes out at 35 MPH.

Comment: why do you think too light would mean a long time to accelerate?  In any case this is really too broad a question for this forum.

Comment: If the car was very heavy it could accelerate a lot better than a car that was very light because the weight of the car pushes down on the wheels making them more efficient.

Comment: @DanielTurczynskyj You had an answer 12 hours ago explaining why a heavy car does not accelerate faster.

Comment: Here‘s a plan: you leave your PC, go outside and try pushing both a bike and a car in neutral until they roll at, say, some relaxed jogging speed. Come back to us and tell us what took you longer and what was more exhausting

Answer (score 4):

For  any car lighter is better and this goes double for a sports car.

It is true that having less weight over the drive wheels can reduce traction but the gain from less overall mass will always be greater. While car designers will use weight *distribution* to tune handling there are almost no circumstances where you would deliberately add weight, except in say a racing formulas where there is a minimum weight in whcih case you would place ballast (usually lead) to tune weight distribution and meet the minimum weight requirements, assuming your design is under it in the first place.

Acceleration is force/mass so for a given amount of torque less mass always means better acceleration, braking and handling, certainly up to the point where the tyres start to slip.

While adding weight over the drive wheels will improve traction you are always going to lose more than you gain and it is much better to look at tyres, suspension and even aerodynamic down-force to add grip at minimum cost in extra weight.

Equally if your primary goal is high mpg then you won;t want to be accelerating very aggressively in any case.

Comment: If a car is back wheel drive, then wouldn't it be better to put the engine in the back, the trunk for example. And if it was front wheel drive, then you would want the engine in the front.

Comment: @DanielTurczynskyj you should definitely read a bit about weight balance and (for example) handling difficulties with older Porsche sports cars. Or the Skoda Rapid.

Comment: Where can I read about that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building an efficient sports car in the near future, it will probably have some electric drive system, whether it's a hybrid or all-electric car.  If your car has batteries, it's likely to be on the heavier end of sports cars.  A heavier car will put more weight on your tires, increasing the force that your tires can apply before slipping, but F=ma, meaning that a greater force will be required to accelerate your heavier car.

Comment: Is electric better than gasoline powered

Comment: I don't know what you want in a sports car, but the low-end torque available from an electric motor makes an electric or hybrid-electric very appealing from an acceleration standpoint

Answer (score 0):

More mass equals to more inertia. More inertia means more work to accelerate. On the otherhand more mass means more tire friction. More friction means more power from wheels.

But these dont work the same way more mass only gets you so much more friction and the more mass you add the more diminishing your returns are. Also you can artificially increase the downforce independently of things. You can use different rubber etc.

There is noting other than making things lighter you can do to inertia. There is no other technological way to combat it. Purposefully adding weight makes no sense, but since things can not wheigh nothing you have to add it to gain other properties of matter.

For energy consumption less is definitely more, but you might want to optimize other factors too.